# Refactoring Cognitive Services Code in Python in Databricks on Python

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, azure-databricks, azure-cognitive-services

The following code gives the following Print Output:

-------Recognizing business card #1--------
Contact First Name: Chris has confidence: 1.0
Contact Last Name: Smith has confidence: 1.0

The code that provides the above output is:

```
bcUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/master/sdk/formrecognizer/azure-ai-formrecognizer/samples/sample_forms/business_cards/business-card-english.jpg"

poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_business_cards_from_url(bcUrl)
business_cards = poller.result()

for idx, business_card in enumerate(business_cards):
    print("--------Recognizing business card #{}--------".format(idx+1))
    contact_names = business_card.fields.get("ContactNames")
    if contact_names:
        for contact_name in contact_names.value:
            print("Contact First Name: {} has confidence: {}".format(
                contact_name.value["FirstName"].value, contact_name.value["FirstName"].confidence
            ))
            print("Contact Last Name: {} has confidence: {}".format(
                contact_name.value["LastName"].value, contact_name.value["LastName"].confidence
            ))
```

I am trying refactor the code so as to output the results to a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
    
field_list = ["FirstName", "LastName"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=field_list)
bcUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/master/sdk/formrecognizer/azure-ai formrecognizer/samples/sample_forms/business_cards/business-card-english.jpg"
    for blob in container.list_blobs():
      blob_url = container_url + "/" + blob.name
      poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_business_cards_from_url(bcUrl)
      business_cards = poller.result()
      print("Scanning " + blob.name + "...")
      
      for idx, business_card in enumerate(business_cards):
          single_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=field_list)
    
          for field in field_list:
            entry = business_card.fields.get(field)
            
            if entry:
              single_df[field] = [entry.value]
              
          single_df['FileName'] = blob.name
          df = df.append(single_df)
    
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    df
```

However, my code does not provide any output:

Can someone take a look and let know why I'm not getting any output?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to connect ***blob storage***, I got the same kind of ***error***. I just followed the below ***syntax*** for connecting ***blob storage*** and also, I deleted `.json` and some other `.fott` files only I have the PDFs in the container. I run the same code without any problem it is working fine. Please follow below **reference** which has detailed information.

> **Install packages**

[image: Ref1]

> **Connect to Azure Storage Container**

[image: Ref2]

> **Enable Cognitive Services**

[image: Ref3]

> **Send files to Cognitive Services**

[image: Ref4]

**Reference:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQ2NeO4c9iI&t=458s

[Azure Databricks and Form Recognizer - Invalid Image or password protected - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351356/azure-databricks-and-form-recognizer-invalid-image-or-password-protected)

https://github.com/tomweinandy/form_recognizer_demo