# How to perform Azure Databricks with Form Recognizer

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to use the Azure Form Recognizer in Databricks. every time I am getting invalid error.

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351356/azure-databricks-and-form-recognizer-invalid-image-or-password-protected)

My code does not provide any output:

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [OCR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBQO4QdUp6A&t=10s) extract data from PDFs

When I try to connect blob storage I got similar kind of error, Please follow below approach.

**Code:**

> **Install these packages:**

```
pip install azure.storage.blob 
pip install azure.ai.formrecognizer
```

> **Connect to azure databricks to azure storage account**

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

url = "https://<formrecognizer_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<folder_name>"
container = ContainerClient.from_container_url(container_url)

for blob in container.list_blobs():
    blob_url = url + "/" + blob.name
    print(blob_url)
```

> **Enable Congitive Services:**

```
import requests
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import FormRecognizerClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

endpoint = "<cognitiveServices_Endpoint>"
key = "<cognitiveServices_Key>"

form_recognizer_client = FormRecognizerClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key))
```

For more information refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72475152/refactoring-cognitive-services-code-in-python-in-databricks-on-python/72513699#72513699) thread and [Github link](https://github.com/tomweinandy/form_recognizer_demo).